# mysql - group results by id and print

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have "reservation" table (mySql) that contain number of columns: res_id, hotel_id, hotel_name, from_date, to_date.

I would like to select and print html table for each hotel (i'm using PHP). the result should be a title - the name of the hotel, and bellow it a list of reservation for the specific hotel.

I can do GROUP BY:

```
Select * FROM reservation GROUP BY hotel_id
```

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do it, and how do i print the results without checking all the time if the hotel_id was changed?

Thank you in advanced

Comment: That query will raise an exception with newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: It's not group by you need, but order by. The rest is done in php.

Comment: Could you please show an example of input table and expected output

Comment: It's definitely not the right way. In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Why is the name in `reservation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is definitely NOT the right way to approach this.  One method would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM reservation
ORDER BY hotel_id;
```

You would then loop through the result sets.  When the hotel name changes, you would put in the title of the hotel.

Note:  This is a poor data model if it has both the hotel id and name in `reservation`.  This would normally be in `hotel` and you would connect the tables using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT h.hotel_name, r.*
FROM hotels h JOIN
     reservation r
     ON r.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
ORDER BY hotel_id;
```

Using a `LEFT JOIN`, you can even get hotels with no reservations.

Comment: I do have hotel table, and the hotel name only appear there. i just change it for the post here...

Comment: so, do i have to do the printing separation in the PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

How is it that the hotel_id would change? As per your question it seems that hotel_id is a column made for join with a "hotels" table, isn't it?

Regarding the "group by", why would you group by hotel? This would make you loose reservations data, unless you were using some sort of group_concat.

If you want to get the reservations from a specific hotel you could loop through your hotels table and inside your loop you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE hotel_id='QUERIED_HOTEL_ID'
```

Then show the results.

Or you could simply

```
SELECT * FROM reservations
```

And when you get the fetched results you can make a multidimensional php array with 'hotel_id' as top level key and 'res_id' as secondary, like this:

```
$reservations_by_hotel = [];

do {

    $resId = $row['res_id'];
    $hotelId = $row['hotel_id'];

    $reservations_by_hotel[$hotelId][$resId] = $row;

} while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc());
```

Comment: A `do`/`while` will not work, as the `do` part is executed once before each iteration. Should be an ordinary `while` instead.